# flying limbs (meaning)

Tags: meaning

Example ([A Russian Soldier Story](http://lens.blogs.nytimes.com/2015/08/24/a-russian-solider-story/?_r=1#)):

> Mr. Volkov’s photographs that were not deleted are in stark contrast to his previous work, which showcased bruised faces and **flying limbs**. These photographs are subtle and quiet. The young men, ranging in age from 18 to 27, are solemn, baby-faced, and their expressions oscillate between fright, uncertainty and manufactured bravado that hides their fear.

What does that really mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*"Flying limbs"* means bodies moving in an uncontrolled fashion. Two skiers might crash into each other and tumble down a slope, *limbs flying.* A pair of circus acrobats doing triple-twist-gainer-flip trapeze jumps (or whatever) would not have *flying limbs* unless something goes wrong, and they are no longer executing the stunts in a controlled fashion.

In the article the author of your piece linked to, I don't see pictures that seem like good examples of "flying limbs."

Note that the expression *flying limbs* is entirely unrelated to the *flying fists* referred to in that second article

Comment: It doesn't necessarily mean *uncontrolled*; boxers could be described as having flying limbs, as in "They fell upon one another, limbs flying."  It simply means very energetic, whether the energy came from the owner or an event in the world outside.  It could of course also mean, as per Victor's answer, detached limbs literally flying around.

Comment: Hmm...If I saw that phrase (_"They fell upon one another, limbs flying"_) I would think they had literally fallen down.  OTOH, _"They fell upon one another, **fists** flying"_ would evoke a dandy dust-up.

Comment: Seems like a stylistic choice that might be used to indicate the perspective of the narrator/narrative.  "Fists flying" partakes more of the participants presumed seriousness.  "Limbs flying" is perhaps a bit more whimsical or comedic.  They are both reasonably literal.  Also, if one thinks of modern martial art movies, etc., "limbs flying" is a little less banal than "fists flying".

Answer (score -1):

From what I could see on some of his photographs, *flying limbs* can refer to arms extended forward and up in a salute of sorts (or raised with a clenched fist as a gesture of support by football fans).  I have not seen real limbs flying as a result of *an explosion*, for instance, although that is a possibility, if he took photos of the war in Ukraine.